# Summing specific rows and adding it to matched rows as a new attribute wtithout using function or any loops in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

My dataset sample is as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,1,1,4,5,5,4,1,2,3,5,6,2,1,5), 
               v2 = c(11,13,3,42,15,25,44,13,21,73,65,26,52,11,57))
 df2 <- data.frame(v3 = c(1,2,3,0,4,5,6,7))
 df2$newCol = 0
```

I want to do following pseudo code without using function or any loops (library function can be use). Because the dataset is very long (50k rows) and processing common codes is takes long time).

```
for i to length(df2$v3)
    for j to length(df1$v1)
       if (df2$v3[i] == df1$v1[j])
           df2$newCol[i] = df2$newCol[i] + df$v2[j]
```

Comment: What is `newcol`... if it's a new column, how do you initialise...

Comment: @Headpoint all rows 0 in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,1,1,4,5,5,4,1,2,3,5,6,2,1,5), 
                  v2 = c(11,13,3,42,15,25,44,13,21,73,65,26,52,11,57))
df2 <- data.frame(v3 = c(1,2,3,0,4,5,6,7))
```

Your code

```
df2$newCol=0
for (i in 1 :length(df2$v3)){
  for (j in 1: length(df1$v1)){
     if (df2$v3[i] == df1$v1[j]){
      df2$newCol[i] = df2$newCol[i] + df1$v2[j]

      }

    }
}
```

My solution

```
df1_ori=df1# keep it 
df1$sum=ave(df1$v2,df1$v1,FUN=sum)
df1=df1[!duplicated(df1$v1),]
df2$Newcol=df1$sum[match(df2$v3,df1$v1)]
df2[is.na(df2)]=0



df2
  v3 newCol Newcol
1  1     51     51
2  2     73     73
3  3     73     73
4  0      0      0
5  4     86     86
6  5    162    162
7  6     26     26
8  7      0      0
```

Comment: This code changed my dataframes and I lost the repeated rows. I dont want to change my dataframes.

Comment: @JonahThunderbolt added one lane keep the original

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how efficient this is or if it fits your use case, but another way this could be done using `dplyr` is to sum the values first in `df1` for each unique value in `v1` then join the result to `df2`. Any values of `df2$v3` which don't have a matching value in `df1$v1` are set to zero:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(v1) %>% 
  summarise(newCol = sum(v2)) %>%
  right_join(df2, by = c("v1" = "v3")) %>%
  rename(v3 = v1) %>%
  mutate(newCol = coalesce(newCol, 0))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>      v3 newCol
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     51
#> 2     2     73
#> 3     3     73
#> 4     0      0
#> 5     4     86
#> 6     5    162
#> 7     6     26
#> 8     7      0
```